# Is it possible to add permissions on object at field level

Tags: permissions, roles, pimcore, capability

Within the implementation of MDM based on the PIMCORE solution, we wish to segregate data according to user rights. The goal is to restrict access to the attributes of an object according to predefined roles.

The different possibilities were to go through either perspectives or customer views but it is not possible to add more detailed restrictions at the attribute level. The other possibility would be to do specific development in PIMCORE, but this is still a bit expensive.

In your opinion, is there a native way to manage this data segregation in PIMCORE? Or do you have a way to do this on a specific development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following possibilities:

1. Custom layouts

   Custom Layouts give you the possibility to define different views on data objects for certain users. You can hide certain fields from the admin backend to certain users which is a great way to achieve what you want. The drawback is that this is not suited for "high-security scenarios" as the full data objects are still sent in the background.

   So if the data is highly secure it might be readable within the communication streams (https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Class_Settings/Custom_Layouts.html).
2. Encrypted fields

   Maybe you could use encrypted fields to further improve security. A combination of custom layouts and encrypted fields should at least make data unreadable to certain users (https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Others.html). I am not 100% sure, it should be tested.
3. Workflows

   You could use Workflows in order to restrict certain actions on objects depending on the current object state. Workflows have a possibility to fully implement permissions and dissallow certain actions for certain users.

   https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Workflow_Management/Permissions.html
4. Use Relations

   This is probably one of the simplest and best solutions. Create seperate classes for the sensitive data and connect the data objects via Many-To-One or Many-To-Many relationships and restrict access on them. This way you can ensure that certain users never can access or edit the sensitive data.

   https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Relation_Types.html